# How to get collection values in Kotlin lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have two collections: A and B. Both of them consist of equal amount of chars. I zip them. Then I need to count pairs of the same elements, like 'A' and 'A'. I need to write a predicate, but I can't find the way to get both elements from a zipped collection.
I've tried something like this:

```
    val num = A.zip(B).count { it.i: Int, it.j:Int -> it.i == it.j}
```

and this:

```
    val num = A.zip(guess).count { it[0] == it[2] }
```

But it doesn't work. **How can I reach both elements from these sub lists of chars?**
I looked into Kotlin official examples but there are only easy ones:

```
val evenCount = numbers.count { it % 2 == 0 }
```

Comment: Do you want to count the same chars in the same position or the same chars independent of their position in the two strings? Example: would "abc" and "axb" return 1 (for 'a') or 2 (for 'a' and 'b')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count the pairs of elements in two lists, you're very close. By calling `zip` you are given a `Pair`. You can count the resulting list of `Pair` objects by accessing their `first` and `second` parts and seeing if they match (using `==`).

```
// Assumptions...
val a = listOf("A", "B", "D")
val b = listOf("A", "B", "C")

// Count where both elements of the zipped pair match
return a.zip(b).count { it.first == it.second }
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to deconstruct the resulting `Pair` given by `.zip` when using `.count`, you need to put the "deconstructor" into parentheses.

```
a.zip(b).count { (aElement, bElement) -> aElemant == bElement }
```

You could also just ignore that and just access it directly.

```
a.zip(b).count { it.first == it.second }
```